# Using RCNN to autocrop an image

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, nvidia-digits

I am new to machine learning. I've been messing around with NVIDIA Digits to train a new dataset. My dataset however is too inaccurate and I think it is because there is too much background in the image that it is getting confused as to what the actual object is. My question:

Is there a way (possibly using RCNN) to crop out the background and then proceed to train using the cropped image? The object is consistent (ex only one object like a singular person but there may be people in the background) and always by itself.

Comment: How big is your dataset? How many categories and how many images do you have in each categories?

Comment: @gyurisc Roughly 10,000 images and 20 categories so max of 500 images per category.